# Nonmeasurable sets are required in Locally Compact Hausdorff Spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I realized the only example of a nonmeasurable set I had seen (a vitali set) crucially relies on the translation invariance of the lebesgue measure. I looked around for other examples of nonmeasurable sets, and struggled to find any. This led me to ask if there are measures which can be defined on the entire powerset algebra.

While looking into this, I found [an article](http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/volii/2/measure-cardinality.pdf) which says

> Radon measures on uncountable locally compact Hausdorff spaces... must exclude a class of problematic sets to be defined

Why is it the case that not every set can be measurable in a locally compact hausdorff space? The obvious generalization of a vitali set doesn't seem to work, as there is no natural choice of group action to leverage.

Thanks in advance ^_^